# How can we get bluetooth permission popup in react-native-expo

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, expo

I am trying like that it will call through useEffect or any event.

```html
 const askPermission=async()=>{
    await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,{
            title: 'Bluetoth Permission',
            message: 'This app needs access to your bluetooth.',
            buttonPositive: 'OK',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }
    );
    await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
    );
}
```

But its not working for me.

Comment: What does not work ? were an exception thrown?
Are you using a managed or a bare workflow ?